# How to separate $routeParams into divs

Tags: angularjs, url-routing, factory, livesearch

I have a live search box fed with a factory. I'm using `$routeParams` to extract information from the URL, but can't seem to get it working completely. I'm trying to break up the URL into segments and so I can style and position `truckData.firstName` and `truckData.company` on two lines. I also can't figure out how to include an image w/ `$routeParams`. Suggestions are greatly appreciated!

app.js:

```
var myApp = angular.module('myApp', ['ngRoute']);

 myApp.config(function ($routeProvider) {

  $routeProvider

      .when('/', {
          templateUrl: 'pages/main.html',
          controller: 'vehicleController'
      })

      .when('/:firstName', {
          templateUrl: 'pages/driverData.html',
          controller: 'profileController'
      })


});


myApp.controller('vehicleController', function($scope, truckData) {
  $scope.vehicleSearch = truckData;
});


myApp.controller('profileController', ['$scope', '$routeParams', function($scope, $routeParams) {

$scope.model = {
    firstName: $routeParams.firstName
}
}]);


myApp.factory('truckData', function () {
  var truckData = {};
  truckData.drivers = [
    {
        firstName: "John",
        lastName: "Doe",
        company: "Company XYZ",
        vehicle: "1234",
        image: ??
    },

    {
        firstName: "Jane",
        lastName: "Doe",
        job: "Designer",
        vehicle: "5678",
        image: ??
    },

    {
        firstName: "Jake",
        lastName: "Doe",
        job: "Designer",
        vehicle: "9012",
        image: ??
    }

  ];
  return truckData;
});
```

driverData.html:

```
<h3>{{ model.firstName }}</h3>
```

main.html:

```
<h5>ENTER VEHICLE ID (OR UA) TO FIND A VEHICLE</h5>

<div id="results">
  <img src="images/findVehicle.png" class="vehicleSearch">
    <input type="text" placeholder="Enter Name or Vehicle ID" ng-model="search">
<button class="btn btn-info" type="search">submit</button>

<table width="224" align="center" ng-show="(filteredData = (vehicleSearch.drivers | filter:search)) && search && search.length >= 1">
    <tr ng-repeat="truck in filteredData">


        <td width="119" align="left"><a id="link-4" href="index.htm#/{{ truck.firstName }}" name="xx" ng-click="value = 4">{{"  #" + truck.vehicle}}</a></td>
    </tr>
</table>
```

index.html:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en-us" ng-app="myApp">
<head>

    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=Edge">
    <meta charset="UTF-8">

    <!-- BOOTSTRAP & FONT AWESOME -->
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="//netdna.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.2.0/css/bootstrap.min.css" />

    <!-- CUSTOM STYLES -->
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/main.css" />
    <style>
        html, body, input, select, textarea
        {
            font-size: 1.05em;
        }
    </style>

    <script src="//code.angularjs.org/1.3.0-rc.1/angular.min.js"></script>
    <script src="//code.angularjs.org/1.3.0-rc.1/angular-route.min.js"></script>

    <!-- ANGULAR PROJECT CODE -->
    <script src="app.js"></script>
</head>
<body>

    <header>
        <nav class="navbar navbar-default">
        <div class="container">
            <div class="navbar-header">
                <p><img src="images/findVehicle.png">Find a Vehicle</p>
            </div>
            <ul class="nav navbar-nav navbar-right">
                <li><a href="#"><i class="fa fa-home"></i> Home</a></li>
                <li><a href="#/second"><i></i> Second</a></li>
            </ul>
        </div>
        </nav>
    </header>

    <div class="container">

        <div ng-view></div>

    </div>

</body>
```

main.css:

```
.navbar-default {
    background-color: #323a45;
    border-radius: 0;
}

.navbar-header p {
    color: #f1f1f3;
    padding-top: 12px;
}

.container {
    text-align: center;
}

body {
    background-color: #dfe5e8;
}

#results {
    margin: 0 0 0 15px;
}

.searchIcon {
    margin-right: -20px;
}

h5 {
    color: #5e6d81;
}

p img {
    margin-right: 15px;
}

::-webkit-input-placeholder {
   color: #a1b1bc;
   font-size: 10pt;
   padding: 3pt 0 0 4pt;
}

:-moz-placeholder { /* Firefox 18- */
   color: #a1b1bc;  
}

::-moz-placeholder {  /* Firefox 19+ */
   color: #a1b1bc;  
}

:-ms-input-placeholder {  
   color: #a1b1bc;  
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You shouldn't be passing all of the information through the $routeParams. Instead, you should pass a unique identifier for a particular truck and then you can call back to your factory to get the information for the truck selected.

I'll use vehicle number as the ID for an example. I'm also going to switch your factory to using promises, which it would be more likely to return with real data.

Your vehicleController would become:

```
myApp.controller('vehicleController', ['$scope', 'truckData', function($scope, truckData) {
    truckData.getTrucks().then(function(trucks) {
      $scope.vehicleSearch = trucks;
    });
}]);
```

Your profileController would become:

```
myApp.controller('profileController', ['$scope', '$routeParams', 'truckData', function($scope, $routeParams, truckData) {
    var vehicleNumber = $routeParams.vehicle;

    truckData.getTruckDriver(vehicleNumber).then(function (truck) {
        $scope.model = truck
    });
}]);
```

Your factory would then look like:

```
myApp.factory('truckData', ['$q', function ($q) {
    var truckData = {};
    truckData.drivers = [ 
        //load drivers here
    ];

    var getTruckDriver = function(vehicleNumber) {
         var deferred = $q.defer();

         for (var i = 0; i++; i < truckData.drivers.length) {
              if (truckData.drivers[i].vehicle === vehicleNumber {
                  deferred.resolve(truckData.drivers[i]);
              }
         }

         return deferred;
    }

    var getTrucks = function() {
         var deferred = $q.defer();
         deferred.resolve(truckData);
         return deferred;
    }

    return {
        getTrucks: getTrucks,
        getTruckDriver: getTruckDriver
    }
}]);
```

Once you switch to this pattern, you don't have to worry about passing an image on the route, you can just have the image path as part of the driver data.

I'm not doing any error handling on the promises for this example, but for real world applications you should

Comment: Thank you, Jaspers. The new code is throwing an error and it looks to be coming from the .then method in the first controller. Can you please explain what you're doing in the last section of the factory by returning getTrucks: getTrucks?

Comment: Forgot to return the promise in my methods. I've updated my code to be more correct. The last section returns an object with a getTrucks method that has the value of the getTrucks function defined above it.

Comment: Thanks for your help, Jaspers. Could truckData.getTrucks().then(function(trucks) be missing something or structured incorrectly? I'm studying your code (don't understand all of it) and looks like there should be a .get(). The .then() is throwing an error.

Comment: Hi Jaspers. One more question. Can you explain what's happening with this line of code and how I can use 'truck':    $scope.model = truck;

Comment: `truck` is the value being returned by the promise, the driver that is passed in to deferred.resolve() in the service.. In the code above, I am just assigning it the model property on the scope.